# How can i loop over this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is the data i have and i want to loop over it in javascript since it is not an array map is not working can anybody help me loop over it or convert it into array then loop?

```
{
"7/15/2021": {
    "date": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
    "value": [
        "e1",
        "e 2"
    ]
},
"7/12/2021": {
    "date": "2021-07-12T00:00:00",
    "value": [
        "e 3",
        "4",
        "e 5",
        "e 6"
    ]
}}
```

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)/[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)/[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)/[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an object you can make use of `Object.keys` which will return the list of keys in an object.

```js
const data = {
  "7/15/2021": {
    "date": "2021-07-15T00:00:00",
    "value": [
      "e1",
      "e 2"
    ]
  },
  "7/12/2021": {
    "date": "2021-07-12T00:00:00",
    "value": [
      "e 3",
      "4",
      "e 5",
      "e 6"
    ]
  }
}
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  console.log('Key -> ', key);
  Object.keys(data[key]).forEach((internalKey) => {
    console.log('Internal Key -> ', internalKey);
    if (Array.isArray(data[key][internalKey])) {
      data[key][internalKey].forEach((node) => {
        console.log('data node -> ', node);
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: @KrishnaKalyana Welcome happy to have an upvote.

Comment: I dont have reputation above 15 otherwise i would definitely give that :(